# Show actual execution plan of a mysql query

Tags: mysql, sql, explain

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the MySQL equivalent of PostgreSQL's EXPLAIN ANALYZE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6812655/what-is-the-mysql-equivalent-of-postgresqls-explain-analyze)

I was wondering if there is a way in mysql to show the actual steps of the execution plan of an executed query.

For instance `EXPLAIN SELECT ...` shows what mysql WOULD do, but is there a way to actually execute the query and display the execution plan used in the execution?

I see that postgreSQL provides this functionality via `EXPLAIN ANALYZE SELECT...`

Is there any equivalent functionality in MySQL?

Comment: I don't think there is anything in MySQL that will give you the level of detail a PostgreSQL plan gives you. The only thing that somehow goes into that direction is the "profiler": http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/show-profiles.html

Comment: 1 year ago. 5 seconds searching: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6812655/what-is-the-mysql-equivalent-of-postgresqls-explain-analyze

Comment: @spencer7593: the manual clearly states that MySQL shows an "estimate" as well - and ramirez is **not** comparing to Oracle but to PostgreSQL

Comment: @spencer7593: from here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/explain.html Quote: "*MySQL explains how it **would** process the statement*". And the experience that a statement takes hardly any time to "explain" even when it takes minutes to run.